# Using quarter function in conjunction of hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am having a query like follows,

```
SELECT 
    SUM(field1 * field2) AS summation,
    MONTH(date_field) AS months
FROM
    some_table
    where QUARTER(date_field) = QUARTER(CURDATE())
GROUP BY MONTH(date_field)
```

I want to write the above in hibernate, however I am unable to figure out how to write the quarter functionality in conjunction of hibernate. Till now I have the  following hibernate criteria without the quarter functionality as follows,

```
ProjectionList proj = Projections.projectionList();

proj.add(Projections.sqlProjection("sum(field1 * field2) AS summation", new String[] { "summation" }, new Type[] {StandardBasicTypes.BIG_INTEGER }));

proj.add(Projections.sqlGroupProjection("month(date_field)  as months",  new String[] { "months" }, new Type[] { StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER }));

Criteria cr = getSession().createCriteria(some_table.class).setProjection(proj).add(conjunction);
```

I am stuck in how to write the conjunction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what the query says is that the date_field belongs to the current quarter, so the workaround I got is like this,

```
conjunction.add(Restrictions.between("date_field",getFirstDayOfCurrentQuarter(),getLastDayOfCurrentQuarter() ));
```

where the two functions getFirstDayOfCurrentQuarter() and getLastDayOfCurrentQuarter() gives the first and last date of the current quarter. These functions are as follows,

```
private static Date getFirstDayOfCurrentQuarter() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)/3 * 3);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        return cal.getTime();
    }

    private static Date getLastDayOfCurrentQuarter() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)/3 * 3 + 2);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        return cal.getTime();
    }
```